# CSS display: table-cell float causes extra space in the text

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am having an issue with a design using table layout. So I am using 2 asides for the side navigation and a centered main section content (which is all wrapped in a section wrapper)
My text in the section wrapper has some white spacing at the top. It is due to the float left and right on the aside elements. If I remove them, the text goes back to the top but then my aside elements occupy the entire space (I have used a box border around the aside to show it, as I want to colour the aside element for my design so I don't want it to take the entire space of the main body-content)

I have tried using top:0% but no luck.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chou_one/nPAJc/

Comment: why are you using table vs block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it by changing the width and float.

According to your code, I made some changes:

I changed the float in `#side-news2` from `right` to `left`.
And add `width: 30%` to `#side-news`, `#side-news2`, and `#section-wrapper`.
Note that all of the `width` (`30%` + `30%` + `30%`) cannot exceed the one in `#body-content` (which is set to be `90%`)

```
#body-content {
    display: table;
    width:90%;     
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: lightblue;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); /* highlight on inner box */
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; /* FF */
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; /* Safari, Chrome */
    border-radius: 3px; /* modern browsers */    
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);    
}

#side-news {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:30%;
        top:0%;
    display:table-cell;    
    float:left;
    list-style:none;    
}

#side-news2 {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:30%;
    display:table-cell;    
    float:left;
    list-style:none;      
}
#section-wrapper {
    width:30%;
    display:table-cell;  
    margin: 0px;
    float:left;
    top:0%;
    margin-top:0%;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-top:0%;
}
```

​

Comment: amazing...thanks a ton...just gotta love  the stackoverflow forum

Comment: out of curiosity I want to know for knowledge why does the float:right not allow this to happen? I tried using the .clearfix and overflow: auto but it didn't seem to work..

Comment: `float:right` works, but there will be some space between the main content and the right `aside` bar. (As you can see now in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nPAJc/26/) )